# XML parsing error in PHP after CURL

Tags: php, curl, xml-parsing

I have obtained such a response after executing one curl request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mp_response>
<response_element>
<merchantid>
36573dkjdkjds3987398
</merchantid>
<orderid>
1
</orderid>
<responsecode>
23
</responsecode>
<description>
Transaction Payout Completed
</description>
</response_element>
</mp_response>
```

But when I use functions like

```
new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);
simplexml_load_string($data)
```

etc.
I get an error like

```
Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found
```

What should I do?

Comment: can you post the code how you read the data out of curl, it sounds like your string is urlencoded

Comment: Looks like your `$xml_str` or `$data` does not contain any XML.

Answer (score 0):

After closing curl use "**simplexml_load_string($string)**"
$string is a variable which stores curl_exec();
Then take a variable for retrieving data from the xml.
e.g.,

```
$data=simple_load_string($string);
$response=$data->response_element->merchantid;
```